Cannot resolved keyword 'date_created' into field
I have a problem with runserver on PowerShell.
entries_detail.html:
<article>
    <h2>{{ entry.date_created|date:'Y-m-d H:i' }}</h2>
    <h3>{{ entry.title }}</h3>
    <p>{{ entry.content }}</p>
</article>

entries_list.html:
{% for entry in entry_list %}
    <article>
        <h2 class="{{ entry.date_created|date:'l' }}">
            {{ entry.date_created|date:'Y-m-d H:i' }}
        </h2>
        <h3>
            <a href="{% url 'entry-detail' entry.id %}">
                {{ entry.title }}
            </a>
        </h3>
    </article>
{% endfor %}


views.py:
from django.views.generic import (
    DetailView,
    ListView,
)
from django.db import models

from .models import Entry

---


class EntryListView(ListView):
    model = Entry
    queryset = Entry.objects.all().order_by("-date_created")


class EntryDetailView(DetailView):
    model = Entry


I tried to run python manage.py runserver on PowerShell and I got the result:
django.core.exceptions.FieldError: Cannot resolve keyword 'date_created' into field. Choices are: content, data_created, id, title


Your field name in models.py is data_created not date_created

You have typo mistake at data_created field of Entry model in queryset = Entry.objects.all().order_by("-date_created") you try order_by with -date_created so its raise error invalid filed
You need to write queryset queryset = Entry.objects.all().order_by("-data_created")
Here you need to correct -data_created") instead of -date_created")
